# How to: Flask Python / WTForms Adding dynamic field

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

How we can generate fields dynamically in flask with wtf forms without using java script DOM to add fields like here in this link:
    http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/
for example adding a field or when we delete the field to delete a set on database like in the images down here.

Form with one row:
[Form with one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Qd3.png)

Form with multiple rows:
[Form with multiple rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlXKD.png)

```html
{{ form.hidden_tag() }} 
{{ form.Book }}
{{ form.ISBN }} 
{{ form.Price }} 

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

And my python class form

```html
class BookForm(FlaskForm):

    isbn = StringField("ISBN",[validators.DataRequired("Please enter your ISBN number.")])
    title = StringField("Titile",[validators.DataRequired("Please enter your Book Title.")])
    price = FloatField("Price")
```

I saw some people proposing some class_ thing but i didn't understand that.

Comment: I am willing to use SQLAlchemy with the wtf and the dynamic inserting an X number of fields

Comment: Anyone to help?